# Cannot convert to expected argument type 'AuthDataResultCallback?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I seem to get an error stating:

Cannot convert value of type '(User?, _) -> ()' to expected argument type 'AuthDataResultCallback?' (aka 'Optional<(Optional, Optional) -> ()>')

in this line of code:

```
         Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user:User?, error) in
```

I believe it's due to a Firebase update.

User is connected to the following class:

```
class User: NSObject {
var id: String?
var name: String?
var email: String?
var profileImageUrl: String?
var isSelected: Bool = false
var addedUser: Bool = false

func contactId() -> String? {
    return (id)
}
}
```

Hoping you can help me figure out the correction in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it like

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
   // ...
   guard let user = authResult.user else { return }
}
```

here user is of type `FIRUser` not your custom class `User`